# How to format the date during unit-test with Ext JS format method?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, date, testing, extjs

I'm try to write a proper unit-test for method below. I'm trying to test the assertion within formatted date. Thusly trying to use [Ext.Date.format](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.2/classic/Ext.Date.html#method-format) method in assertion but it returns as **failed**.

How can i format the given and expected date to `d.m.Y`? (I'm not allowed to change method itself!)

```
dateAdd: function (aDate, aInterval, aValue) {
        var me = this;

        aDate = aDate || me.today();
        aInterval = aInterval || Ext.Date.DAY;
        aValue = aValue || 1;

        return Ext.Date.add(aDate, aInterval, aValue);
    },
```

and the test assertion;

```
t.describe('dateAdd() method', function(t) {
    t.it('should interval the given date', function(t) {
        t.expect(MyApp.dateAdd(new Date(Ext.Date.format('01.01.2018', 'd.m.Y')), Ext.Date.DAY, 1)).toBe('02.01.2018');
    });
});

// Result: 
// Failed assertion `expect(got).toBe(need)` at line 64 of 01-unit-tests.js
// Got  : "Invalid Date"
// Need : "02.01.2018"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the ExtJs documentation, [Ext.Date.add](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.5.0/modern/Ext.Date.html#method-add) returns a Date object which you compare with a String.
When you exchange the String with a Date object it should work.

```
t.describe('dateAdd() method', function(t) {
    t.it('should interval the given date', function(t) {
        var expectedDate = Ext.Date.format('02.01.2018', 'd.m.Y');
        t.expect(MyApp.dateAdd(new Date(Ext.Date.format('01.01.2018', 'd.m.Y')), Ext.Date.DAY, 1)).toBe(expectedDate);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should check your date pattern, I use these patterns as guide :

```
Ext.Date.patterns = 
 {
    ISO8601Long:"Y-m-d H:i:s",
    ISO8601Short:"Y-m-d",
    ShortDate: "n/j/Y",
    LongDate: "l, F d, Y",
    FullDateTime: "l, F d, Y g:i:s A",
    MonthDay: "F d",
    ShortTime: "g:i A",
    LongTime: "g:i:s A",
    SortableDateTime: "Y-m-d\\TH:i:s",
    UniversalSortableDateTime: "Y-m-d H:i:sO",
    YearMonth: "F, Y"
};
```